# Get new (not old) post inside transition_post_status hook

Tags: hooks, post-status

Following up the ticket ['transition_post_status' is executed before 'save_post'](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19074), I'm still struggling how to access the **new** `$post` (after it has been saved) inside a `transition_post_status` hook. Right now, I'm getting the old $post data (before it has been saved).

Example:

```
add_action('transition_post_status','myfunc',10,3);
function myfunc($new_status,$old_status,$post){

 if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish') {
 // a post is getting published

    if(!check_my_post($post->ID)){ //how can I get the saved/new post here?
           ...
        // do something     
    }     
  }    
 }
```

Changing priorities does not make any difference.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: While the hook does fire before `save_post` one, both of them fire after data had been actually updated and should pass new instance. Your code not aligned with your assumptions somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_transition_post_status), if you use `wp_transition_post_status()` you will get both the old version and the new version.

```
 wp_transition_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
```

The ticket also says that the post type needs to support revisions for the save to work.

> Check the post type of the post objects before doing anything.
>
> If your post type supported revisions, you'd see both actions fire
>   twice -- transition then save for the revision, transition then save
>   for the post.

Would it be possible for you to use `wp_transition_post_status()`? And have you ensured that your post type [supports revisions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)?